# Isomorphism between $L^q$ and $(L^p)^*$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Theorem 6.15 in Folland states

> Let $p$ and $q$ be conjugate exponents. If $1 < p < \infty$, for each $\phi \in (L^p)^*$ there exists $g \in L^q$ such that $\phi(f) = \int fg$ for all $f \in L^p$, and hence $L^q$ is isometrically isomorphic to $(L^p)^*$. The same conclusion holds for $p = 1$ provided $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

I have gone through the proof of the theorem and it is clear to me that there the map $g \mapsto \phi_g(f) = \int fg$ is indeed a surjection. However, I am having trouble seeing how the second part of the theorem holds, namely that $L^q$ is isometrically isomorphic to $(L^p)^*$. For this we would require some type of uniqueness in that every $\phi \in (L^p)^*$ corresponds to a *unique* $g \in L^q$, however this was not shown.

How does the injectivity and isometric part of the theorem follow?

Comment: Start by proving the isometry as this implies injectivity. For some $g\in L^q$ Hölder's inequality will give you $|\phi_g(f)|\leq\lVert f\rVert_p\lVert g\rVert_q$ for all $f\in L^p$. This implies $\lVert\phi_g\rVert\leq\lVert g\rVert_q$. To prove the opposite inequality you need to come up with a clever $f\in L^p$ such that $|\phi_g(f)|=\lVert f\lVert_p\lVert g\rVert_q$.

Comment: @jakobdt Apologies if this is elementary, but how does isometry imply injectivity?

Comment: Let $L\colon V\to W$ be a linear map between vector spaces, and assume that $L$ is an isometry. If $Lv_1=Lv_2$ then $0=\lVert L(v_1-v_2)\rVert=\lVert v_1-v_2\rVert$. Hence, $v_1-v_2=0$. This proves that $L$ is injective.

Comment: Essentially, $L$ is injective if and only if the kernel is $\{0\}$. Indeed, if $L$ is an isometry and $v$ is in the kernel you have $0=\lVert Lv\rVert=\lVert v\rVert$ which implies $v=0$.

Comment: @jakobdt Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g_1,g_2 \in L^{q}$ and $\int fg_1=\int fg_2$ for all $f \in L^{p}$ then $\int_E g_1 =\int_E g_2$ for every set $E$ of finite measure. This implies that $g_1=g_2$ almost everywhere.

Comment: By considering $f=1_E$, where $1_E$ is the [indicator function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $E$, right?

Comment: @Filippo That is how I interpreted, yes.